# Putting value into Textbox upon clicking Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am currently trying to make a wallpaper changer for my page.

At the minute, I would like to put the URL of a wallpaper into a text box when it's respective DIV option in a CSS menu is clicked.

Here is my JQuery

```
$("div.bg8").click( function() {
var BackgroundURL = 'Styles/hongkongskyline.jpg'; 
var TheTextBox = document.getElementById('<%=BackgroundsTxt.ClientID%>'); 
TheTextBox.value= BackgroundURL; 
alert('This has worked'); });
```

.. and my HTML...

```
 <ul><li class="#cssmenu"><a>
  <div id="bg8" runat="server">
    <table style="height: 16px; width:33%;"> 
     <tr>
     <td>
     <img src='Styles/hongkongskyline.jpg' width="34px" height="32px" /></td>  <td>Hong Kong Skyline                                                                                       </td> 
     </tr> 
    </table>
   </div>
</a></li></ul>
```

Unfortunately, nothing seems to be happening when I click the DIV..

Does anybody see any problems which I can't?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems here.

First, you aren't referring to your div's ID in your jQuery - you're referring to a class called bg8. Try this:

```
$("#bg8")...
```

Next, you're mixing in some native-dom stuff into your jQuery. Instead of

```
document.getElementById('<%=BackgroundsTxt.ClientID%>');
```

try

```
$("#<%=BackgroundsTxt.ClientID%>");
```

and make sure the ID is resolved by looking at the source to your page.

And lastly, to set the value of the textbox:

```
theTextBox.val(BackgroundURL);
```

Your whole function could be

```
$("#bg8").click( function() {
    $("#<%=BackgroundsTxt.ClientID%>").val('Styles/hongkongskyline.jpg'); 
    alert('This has worked');
});
```

My strategy is to test event handlers with simple alerts before moving on to the real logic.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's really helped out a newbie to jQuery... I've got the alert coming up now, so progress there!

Answer (score 1):

your jQuery states $('div.bg8') , this calls for a div with the class bg8,

you have not set the class, but rather the id of your div as bg8

change this: $('div.bg8') to $('#bg8')

;)